# Interpretar este código JS

Tags: javascript

Buen día, quisiera por favor que alguien me ayudara a interpretar este código JS(qué hace el código en general) ya que no me queda muy claro lo que hacen sus validaciones. Muchas gracias

```js
if ("#formCrearBeneficiario" == a || -1 != a.indexOf("ModificarBenef"))var b = {
        errorContainer: a + " #messageBox",
        errorLabelContainer: a + " #messageBoxUL",
        wrapper: "li",
        onfocusout: !1,
        onsubmit: !1,
        rules: {
            selecEmisor: {comboCheck: "0"},
            selecTipoIdentificacion: {comboCheck: "0"},
            numIdentificacion: {required: !0,
notEqual: "000000000000000",
digits: {  
 depends: function(element) {
var a="00";
if($("select[name=selecTipoIdentificacion]")){
a=$("select[name=selecTipoIdentificacion]").val();
}else if($("select[name=tipoIdentificacion]")){
a=$("select[name=tipoIdentificacion]").val();
}
}}}}}
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y Edita la pregunta para añadir algo más de detalle porque tal y como está ahora es bastante amplia: ¿Qué parte en concreto es la que no entiendes? ¿Qué Es lo que hace este código en general? ¿Recibes algún error?

Comment: ya la edité, muchas gracias

Comment: Paula, el problema es que la pregunta es muy amplia y no provee mucha información sobre la misma. Son ~70 líneas de código sin ninguna explicación de qué son o qué hacen. Habrá algo que entenderás y algo que no, ¿qué parte en concreto no entiendes? Además, debes dar algo de contexto: ¿ese código es para validar un formulario? ¿Estás utilizando algún plugin o algo para ello? ¿Recibes algún error al ejecutarlo? (Y si sí, dónde). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Hola, si se está haciendo la validación de un formulario, y concretamente, es la primera parte que no entiendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no se que exactamente quieras pero esto algo asi:

```
// si `a` es igual a "#formCrearBeneficiario" o `a` contega un indice ModificarBenef
if ("#formCrearBeneficiario" == a || -1 != a.indexOf("ModificarBenef"))
    // se declara un objeto que dice 
    var b = {
        // que errorContainer es igual a lo que tenga `a` concatenado con " #messageBoxUL" igual errorLabelContainer
        errorContainer: a + " #messageBox",
        errorLabelContainer: a + " #messageBoxUL",

        //wrapper es igual a li
        wrapper: "li",
        //onfocusout es igual a falso "true es 1 pero negando lo hace falso" igual para onsubmit
        onfocusout: !1,
        onsubmit: !1,

        // las regals creo que es lo mimso explicado anteriormente
        rules: {
            selecEmisor: { comboCheck: "0" },
            selecTipoIdentificacion: { comboCheck: "0" },
            numIdentificacion: {
                required: !0,
                /// notEqual dice igual a multiples 0 supongo que para evitar que se envie solo eso

                notEqual: "000000000000000",
                //digits es igual a una funcion que resive un argumento element
                digits: {
                    depends: function(element) {
                        // se crea una varibale a y se comparan los campos
                        var a = "00";
                        // si existe un select con nombre selecTipoIdentificacion se obtiene su valor
                        if ($("select[name=selecTipoIdentificacion]")) {
                            a = $("select[name=selecTipoIdentificacion]").val();
                        //si existe un select con nombre tipoIdentificacion se obtine su atributo value
                        } else if ($("select[name=tipoIdentificacion]")) {
                            a = $("select[name=tipoIdentificacion]").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hace ese script es obtener todos los selectores de cada elemento dentro de un formulario válido:
primero ve que la variable enviada, en este caso **a** sea identico al selector del formulario seleccionado en este caso refiriendose a un `<form>` con `id="formCrearBeneficiario"` y tambien se revisa que sea otro formulario que modifica datos con `a.indexOf("ModificarBenef")`  ya que si no es así te retornara **-1** el cual se está comparando, por ultimo cuando sea `true` se crea una variable de tipo objeto para obtener todos los selectores dentro de ese formulario para su uso mas adelante.

*NOTA: los selectores son de Jquery.*

Espero poder haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

Dándole un formato más legible al código, podemos ver claramente que se trata de una declaración de un objeto a partir de la validación:

```
if ("#formCrearBeneficiario" == a || -1 != a.indexOf("ModificarBenef"))
    var b = {
        errorContainer: a + " #messageBox",
        errorLabelContainer: a + " #messageBoxUL",
        wrapper: "li",
        onfocusout: !1,
        onsubmit: !1,
        rules: {
            selecEmisor: { comboCheck: "0" },
            selecTipoIdentificacion: { comboCheck: "0" },
            numIdentificacion: {
                required: !0,
                notEqual: "000000000000000",
                digits: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        var a = "00";
                        if ($("select[name=selecTipoIdentificacion]")) {
                            a = $("select[name=selecTipoIdentificacion]").val();
                        } else if ($("select[name=tipoIdentificacion]")) {
                            a = $("select[name=tipoIdentificacion]").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```